# How do I insert data in a view using INSTEAD OF trigger?

Tags: sql-server, view, triggers, insert

Im trying to insert some data inside a view but,I was getting errors that basically told me that I couldn't do that because of a constant or derived field. But anyway, I did a little research and I found out that I have to use a INSTEAD OF to be able to insert the data into the view.

So my question is what is the correct way to write this trigger? This is what I have:

```
ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[AddEmployeeTrigger] on [dbo].[VW_REX_EMPLOYEES]
INSTEAD OF INSERT
AS
BEGIN

  INSERT INTO [dbo].[VW_REX_EMPLOYEES]
       ([Company]
           ,[EmployeeID]
           ,[Emp_Status]
           ,[Emp_LastName1]
           ,[Emp_LastName2]
           ,[Emp_FirstNames]
           ,[Emp_FullName]
           ,[Puesto]
           ,[Emp_Email]
           ,[Emp_SegSoc]
           ,[Emp_BornDate]
           ,[Emp_Hire_Date]
           ,[Emp_Entry_Date]
           ,[Emp_Type]
           ,[Emp_Gender]
           ,[Lab_Type]
           ,[Emp_Department]
           ,[VS]
           ,[Sup_ID]
           ,[Sup_Name]
           ,[Mgr_ID]
           ,[Mgr_Name]
           ,[Cost_Center]
           ,[CC_Description]
           ,[Emp_Shift_ID]
           ,[Mon_Shift]
           ,[Tue_Shift]
           ,[Wed_Shift]
           ,[Thu_Shift]
           ,[Fri_Shift]
           ,[Sat_Shift]
           ,[Sun_Shift]
           ,[TU_TIP_1]
           ,[TU_TIP_2]
           ,[TU_TIP_3]
           ,[TU_TIP_4]
           ,[TU_TIP_5]
           ,[TU_TIP_6]
           ,[TU_TIP_7]
           ,[PERSONAL_EMAIL]
           ,[SANMINA_EMAIL])
     SELECT
          [Company]
           ,[EmployeeID]
           ,[Emp_Status]
           ,[Emp_LastName1]
           ,[Emp_LastName2]
           ,[Emp_FirstNames]
           ,[Emp_FullName]
           ,[Puesto]
           ,[Emp_Email]
           ,[Emp_SegSoc]
           ,[Emp_BornDate]
           ,[Emp_Hire_Date]
           ,[Emp_Entry_Date]
           ,[Emp_Type]
           ,[Emp_Gender]
           ,[Lab_Type]
           ,[Emp_Department]
           ,[VS]
           ,[Sup_ID]
           ,[Sup_Name]
           ,[Mgr_ID]
           ,[Mgr_Name]
           ,[Cost_Center]
           ,[CC_Description]
           ,[Emp_Shift_ID]
           ,[Mon_Shift]
           ,[Tue_Shift]
           ,[Wed_Shift]
           ,[Thu_Shift]
           ,[Fri_Shift]
           ,[Sat_Shift]
           ,[Sun_Shift]
           ,[TU_TIP_1]
           ,[TU_TIP_2]
           ,[TU_TIP_3]
           ,[TU_TIP_4]
           ,[TU_TIP_5]
           ,[TU_TIP_6]
           ,[TU_TIP_7]
           ,[PERSONAL_EMAIL]
           ,[SANMINA_EMAIL] 
    FROM INSERTED;
END;
```

And another question would be that after adding this trigger, can use a simple insert into to add the data?

Update:
Here is the view definition:

```
    SELECT        Company, EmployeeID, Emp_Status, Emp_LastName1, Emp_LastName2, Emp_FirstNames, Emp_FullName, Puesto, Emp_Email, Emp_SegSoc, Emp_BornDate, Emp_Hire_Date, Emp_Entry_Date, Emp_Type, Emp_Gender, Lab_Type, Emp_Department, VS, Sup_ID, Sup_Name, Mgr_ID, Mgr_Name, Cost_Center, CC_Description, Emp_Shift_ID, Mon_Shift, Tue_Shift, Wed_Shift, Thu_Shift, Fri_Shift, Sat_Shift, Sun_Shift, TU_TIP_1, TU_TIP_2, TU_TIP_3,TU_TIP_4, TU_TIP_5, TU_TIP_6, TU_TIP_7, PERSONAL_EMAIL, SANMINA_EMAIL

    FROM (SELECT Company, EmployeeID, Emp_Status, Emp_LastName1, Emp_LastName2, Emp_FirstNames, dbo.InitCap(Emp_FullName) AS Emp_FullName, Puesto, Emp_Email, Emp_SegSoc, Emp_BornDate, Emp_Hire_Date,Emp_Entry_Date, Emp_Type, Emp_Gender, Lab_Type, Emp_Department, VS, Sup_ID, Sup_Name, Mgr_ID, Mgr_Name, Cost_Center, CC_Description, Emp_Shift_ID, Mon_Shift, Tue_Shift, Wed_Shift, Thu_Shift,Fri_Shift, Sat_Shift, Sun_Shift, TU_TIP_1, TU_TIP_2, TU_TIP_3, TU_TIP_4, TU_TIP_5, TU_TIP_6, TU_TIP_7, PERSONAL_EMAIL, 
                                                        
CASE WHEN SANMINA_EMAIL = 'xxxxxx.xxxx@sanmina.com' THEN 'xxxxxx.xxxx@sanmina.com' WHEN SANMINA_EMAIL IS NOT NULL AND SANMINA_EMAIL != '' AND SANMINA_EMAIL LIKE '%@sanmina.com%' THEN SANMINA_EMAIL WHEN Emp_Email IS NOT NULL AND Emp_Email != '' AND Emp_Email LIKE '%@sanmina.com%' THEN Emp_Email WHEN PERSONAL_EMAIL IS NOT NULL AND PERSONAL_EMAIL != '' AND PERSONAL_EMAIL LIKE '%@sanmina.com%' THEN PERSONAL_EMAIL ELSE NULL END AS SANMINA_EMAIL
                              
FROM XXX1AMTRESSXX.TRESS_SANM.dbo.Rex_Employees AS Rex_Employees_1
     WHERE        (Emp_Status = 'S')
     UNION ALL
     SELECT Company, EmployeeID, Emp_Status, Emp_LastName1, Emp_LastName2, Emp_FirstNames, dbo.InitCap(Emp_FullName) AS Emp_FullName, Puesto, Emp_Email, Emp_SegSoc, Emp_BornDate, Emp_Hire_Date, Emp_Entry_Date, Emp_Type, Emp_Gender, Lab_Type, Emp_Department, VS, Sup_ID, Sup_Name, Mgr_ID, Mgr_Name, Cost_Center, CC_Description, Emp_Shift_ID, Mon_Shift, Tue_Shift, Wed_Shift, Thu_Shift, Fri_Shift, Sat_Shift, Sun_Shift, TU_TIP_1, TU_TIP_2, TU_TIP_3, TU_TIP_4, TU_TIP_5, TU_TIP_6, TU_TIP_7, PERSONAL_EMAIL, SANMINA_EMAIL
                   
FROM  SolutionsWebApp.dbo.Tbl_Non_TRESS_EMPLOYEES) AS derivedtbl_1
    WHERE (EmployeeID <> 005000170)
```

Comment: Add the view definition to your question. If the view selects from a single table and you have omitted the problem constant from the column list, this should work (although I suggest adding `SET NOCOUNT ON;` to the trigger).

Comment: Generally, when you are using an instead of trigger on a view, the trigger handles the insert to put the data into the respective table(s), it doesn't just repeat the `INSERT`, which is rather pointless in all honesty.

Comment: @DanGuzman I added the view definition to the post.

Answer (score 0):

I would say one of the fields in your view is as reported, ie a constant or derived field, so you can't insert rows into this view. It has to be a basic simple view for it to work. After all, if you think about it, how can you add data into a derived field? I suggest you insert into the normal table.

Comment: I dont have access to that table so I was figuring out a way to add data throught that view but i guess i'll check for that

Comment: I see. Well, if you don't have access to that table, but you do have access to the view, it sounds like you should not be inserting data, or you don't have permission. I would suggest doing things properly: don't hack. Don't forget the KISS principle.

Comment: Okay, after I get access to that table and I do the insert, the view is going to update or do I have to make it update?

Comment: I'm guessing you don't quite understand what a view is. A view is basically a query over a table, other  view etc. So, if a view is "create view vw_rex_employees as select companyid, employeeid, status, getdate() as nowdate from rex_employees", doing a "select * from vw_rex_employees" is practically the same as "select * from (select companyid, employeeid ... etc ) as f  ". Just do some websearch on understanding views. Im very sorry to say, Stackoverflow is not really the place to ask these very basic questions.